# O que é e como funciona o Pós-Processamento de CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, desempenho, sass

O que seria um pós-processamento de CSS? Eu já tinha ouvido falar em CSS pré-processado, como o Gulp faz quando compila um SASS em CSS. Mas recentemente escutei o termo CSS pós-processado e fiquei sem entender direito o que é e como ele funciona.

O que seria esse prática de pós-processar o CSS, quais vantagens ela traz para o CSS? Melhora a performance ou a manutenção do código?

Como de fato funciona esse pós-processamento, o que ele faz com o meu .css?

Comment: Olá, meu caro! Talvez seja interessante ler isso daqui: https://postcss.org/

Comment: Parece um pré-processador sem transpilador, tem a mesma ideia, exceto transpilar de SCSS, SASS, etc para CSS

Comment: @Costamilam parece, mas é bem mais que isso, ele retira um monte de coisas tipo comentários, classes que não são usadas, classes repetidas, propriedades repetidas, as vezes dependendo do que vc configurar ele faz o short-hand de tudo, e pode até mudar nomos grandes tipo, `header-btn-btn-active{}` para `hba{}`. Lógico que só se usa quando sobre o projeto para produção, não é usado em desenvolvimento pq mais atrapalharia do que ajudaria

Comment: @hugocsl isso também poderia ser feito durante pré-processamento, não?

Comment: @Costamilam alguma parte sim, porém normalmente o pré apenas converte o sass/less/scss em css, acredito que a maioria das ferramentas de pré tenham algumas limitações. E o pós processamento é só na parte final do projeto mesmo, imagina como seria ruim ficar trabalhando em um CSS minificado e com nome de classe diferente do que está no seus SCSS só pq vc fez algo errado. Tipo imagina que vc errou algo no SCSS e foi no CSS conferir o output e está tudo compilado/minifica. Ia mais te atrapalhar do que ajudar

Comment: @hugocsl pode ser gerados outputs diferentes, muitas ferramentas possuem um build de produção e outro de desenvolvimento

Comment: @Costamilam pode até ser sim, essa não é muito minha área, até por isso que deixei a pergunta rss, e tb nuna vi falando de compilado pré css que faça esses tratametos, mas pode ser que exista tb, mas eu desconheço...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um pós-processador de CSS nada mais é que um programa para ajudar no desenvolvimento de códigos CSS.

*Igual o SASS?*

*Não.*

**pré-processamento vs pós-processamento**

Diferente do pré-processamento de códigos (Sass, Lass e Stylus) que, quando processado, seu código é interpretado e é transformado em CSS, o pós-processamento pode atuar diretamente no código CSS para melhorá-lo de alguma forma.

No pré-processamento você instrui a construção do código css. Aqui você tem um controle grande do que será produzido.

No pós-processamento você manda analisar o código e o interpretador altera seguindo suas próprias regras. Você não tem muito controle, até porque o pós-processamento serve para te proteger de si mesmo como veremos a seguir...

---

***[...] quais vantagens ela traz para o CSS? Melhora a performance ou a manutenção do código?***

Depende do pós-processador. O **[cssnano](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano)** por exemplo, apenas compila o código CSS, apagando comentários e deletando coisas inúteis. Ou seja, pode melhorar a performance.

Um pós-processador que tem o intuito de ajudar na manutenção e na produção do código é o **[stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint)**...

> "que ajuda a evitar erros e impor convenções em seus estilos"

Existe também o **[autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)**, o mais famoso, que ajuda no desenvolvimento, gerando os códigos para navegadores distintos e suas respectivas versões. Exemplo:

**entrada.css**

```
body {
    display: flex;
}
```

**saida.css**

```
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```